# Line by line image swing

Tags: java, image, swing, load, preload

I want to show an image as it is downloading, I have the URL, and I am trying to get the image parts like this:

```
InputStream openStream = url.openStream();

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(openStream));
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

         while ((s = dis.read(b)) != -1) {

            os.write(b , 0, s);

            support.firePropertyChange("stream", null, os);

        }
```

This way, any listener get the stream and creates an image, this way:

```
 if("stream".equals(evt.getPropertyName())){
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = (ByteArrayOutputStream) evt.getNewValue();
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            stream.flush();
            Image createImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byteArray);

            this.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(createImage)));

       } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting a "Premature end of JPEG file sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: JPEG datastream contains no image" error, the image is a JPG image format, is there any library or method known to make something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the image decoder, but you could try [`ImageObserver`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html). There's an example in [*Tracking Image Loading: `MediaTracker` and `ImageObserver`*](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/ui/drawing/loadingImages.html).